# Apache POI - Column having non-english characters e.g. Thai and cell empty, then skips the cell

Tags: excel, utf-8, iterator, apache-poi, cell

I am trying to read an excel file (.xlsx) using Apache POI.
One of the column of the file has non-english characters in it e.g. บริษัท พัฒนา จำกัด (มหาชน)

If the cell is having any value, then POI reads the cell properly with correct non-english characters. But, if the cell is empty in that particular column, it reads the next cell for the current column name.

e.g. if the column4 is having special character type and IS NOT empty, then, POI maps column4 with value in that column properly.
But, if the column4 is having special character type and IS empty, then, POI maps column4 with value in column5.

This corrupts the complete structure and cellIterator.

Please let me know what is the problem and how to solve it? Help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: ...continuing the example, it should not map column4 header with value in column5, but, should actually map column4 to empty string and then rest proceeds smoothly. Clueless!

Comment: Did you try reading the [Apache POI documentation on iterating over rows and cells](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator)?

Comment: yes, read that. so was able to find the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I was able to solve this issue. It was simple one though.
`row.cellIterator()` skips all the cells which are null and creates the iterator and hence the mismatch.
Instead use `row.getCell(int index)`. This will not skip the null cells and hence will work for all cells in that particular row. This had nothing to do with the non-English characters. The co-incidence was only for the non-English column, the empty cells were actually null.